# Installing haskell-mode into Emacs on Ubuntu 12

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I'm following [these](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode) instructions to install haskell-mode on Ubuntu 12. However when I get to the point of typing `M-x customize-option RET pac` then Emacs says: no match! All the customizable variables are shown in the picture below.

Any idea what is going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `init.el` file (`~/.emacs.d/init.el`) and place this there:

```
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu"         . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("original"    . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
        ("org"         . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
        ("marmalade"   . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
```

And then do `M-x package-refresh-contents` and you can install `haskell-mode` from there. Also make sure that your Emacs version is >= 24 since `package.el` is bundled with only higher version. If you are using older version, you may have to manually install that package.

Answer (score 0):

This requires `emacs24` or newer.

### First, install `MELPA`:

```
sudo emacs /etc/emacs/site-start.el
```

Paste in this code: (from https://melpa.org/#/getting-started)

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

Save and exit.

### Second, install `haskell-mode`

To get haskell pretty-printing and indentation, do this to install haskell-mode:

```
emacs
M-x package-list-packages RET (Type meta-key and S, then type package-list-packages and hit return)
C-s haskell-mode RET (Type control-S to search, type nginx and hit return to find the haskell-mode package)
i (to mark it to install)
x (to execute installation of marked packages)
```

### Use `haskell-mode`

Haskell mode will load automatically for haskell files. IF you want to load it manually, you can switch into haskell-mode with `M-x haskell-mode`.